# How to find out the endpoint url of a node of a redis cluster via aws cli 'elasticache describe-cache-clusters'?

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, aws-cli

If I run `aws elasticache  describe-cache-clusters` I will get results like this:

```
    {
        "CacheClusterId": "dev-001",
        "ClientDownloadLandingPage": "https://console.aws.amazon.com/elasticache/home#client-download:",
        "CacheNodeType": "cache.t2.small",
        "Engine": "redis",
        "EngineVersion": "5.0.0",
        "CacheClusterStatus": "available",
        "NumCacheNodes": 1,
        "PreferredAvailabilityZone": "us-west-1a",
        "CacheClusterCreateTime": "2019-01-04T03:12:23.477000+00:00",
        "PreferredMaintenanceWindow": "sat:07:00-sat:08:00",
        "PendingModifiedValues": {},
        "CacheSecurityGroups": [],
        "CacheParameterGroup": {
            "CacheParameterGroupName": "default.redis5.0",
            "ParameterApplyStatus": "in-sync",
            "CacheNodeIdsToReboot": []
        },
        "CacheSubnetGroupName": "dev-redis-subnets",
        "AutoMinorVersionUpgrade": true,
        "SecurityGroups": [
            {
                "SecurityGroupId": "sg-0600888999884b1",
                "Status": "active"
            }
        ],
        "ReplicationGroupId": "dev",
        "SnapshotRetentionLimit": 1,
        "SnapshotWindow": "06:00-07:00",
        "AuthTokenEnabled": true,
        "TransitEncryptionEnabled": true,
        "AtRestEncryptionEnabled": true
    }
```

However it does not show me the endpoint of each node (in the form of `dev-0001-001.dev.cbbxt9.use1.cache.amazonaws.com`)

Which aws cli allows me to retrieve node level info of a redis clusteR?

Answer (score 2):

To determine cache node endpoints and port numbers, use the command describe-cache-clusters with the --show-cache-node-info parameter.

`aws elasticache describe-cache-clusters --show-cache-node-info`

The fully qualified DNS names and port numbers are in the Endpoint section of the output.

**Reference**

[Finding Node Endpoints and Ports](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/mem-ug/ClientConfig.FindingEndpointsAndPorts.html)